# tortoise svn is not merging code

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, branching-and-merging

Here are the steps I performed. I have 2 branches one is dev branch and other private branch created from dev branch. After few days without any update or commit to my private branch I tried to merge like this,

```
Merge From dev branch to my private branch - status ok
```

then

```
Committed my private branch (containing my changes and dev change) - status ok
```

then

```
Merged from private branch to dev branch (got a lot of tree conflicts) - status ok
```

After successful merge, I right clicked on my folder and clicked Resolved, its removes all the yellow triangle icons from folders. But when I checked my dev branch folder locally I found no changes from my private branch. Whats wrong?

Comment: The conflicted files are the same you altered in your private branch?

Comment: No, they are not same

Answer (score 0):

You probably merged the dev branch to your private again.

First, is needed to switch to your dev branch and then reintegrate the private branch.